# How to cast DataTableReader object to bytes array?

Tags: c#, .net

I get data from Database and from local XML file. I use MySqlReader to get data from Database by select query and I use DataTableReader object to get data from XML.

MySqlReader can cast bytes array but DataTableReader can't cast in bytes array.

```
//following block is working fine
MySqlDataReader mySqlReader = new MySqlDataReader();
mySqlReader = it will get data from database by select query

Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.Image = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ByteImageConverter.FromByteArray((byte[])mySqlReader["profilePic"]); 

//following block is not working. Error : "unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Bytes[]'"
DataTable dtEmployee = new DataTable();
dtEmployee = dataset.Tables[0];
DataTableReader dtReader = dtEmployee.CreateDataReader();

Employee employee = new Employee();
//error throws here
employee.Image = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ByteImageConverter.FromByteArray((byte[])dtReader["profilePic"]);
```

Can anybody please suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your MySQL table probably has a BLOB type for the 'ProfilePic' and thus it can be casted to a byte array, but, how is the binary data stored in the XML? your error suggest that it's stored as a String, probably in Base64 so try using [Convert.FromBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
employee.Image = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ByteImageConverter.FromByteArray((byte[])Convert.FromBase64String(dtReader["profilePic"]));
```

if your binary data is stored in another format, you'll need another converter...